# Where do I write MySQL trigger 

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I didn't write any trigger for my works. Now i want to know how to write trigger and where do I write it. Is it possible to write trigger as SQL query in phpmyadmin.

Please help me to write a simple trigger...

I tried like below

```
Create Trigger sales_bi_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON sales
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE num_row INTEGER ;
DECLARE tot_rows INTEGER ;
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO tot_rows
FROM sales
WHERE employee_id = NEW.employee_id ;
   IF num_row > 0 THEN
       UPDATE perfomance 
    SET total_sales = NEW.sale_amt + total_sales,
    ave_sale = total_sales/(tot_rows + 1)
    WHERE employee_id = NEW.employee_id ;
   ELSE
   INSERT INTO perfomance
(employee_id, name, total_sales,ave_sale)
VALUES (NEW.employee_id, NEW.name, NEW.sale_amt, NEW.sale_amt) ;
   END IF ;
```

Thanks in advance
Nisanth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In phpMyAdmin you can create the trigger in the SQL window.

You may have to set the delimieter to something like "$$" instead of the default ";". You can change this easily from the bottom of the SQL window.

[Delimiter in phpMyAdmin http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/9144/phpmyadmin.jpg](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/9144/phpmyadmin.jpg)

In addition, make sure you close your trigger block with the `END` command, which is missing from your example.

Comment: not related to question or your answer - png screenshots will look better with less size ;-)

Comment: Hi Daniel ,
If u don't mind can u write a simple code . I tried lot of time but got some sql syntax error

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 20  

This was my error

Comment: @Nisanth: I was going to comment about the `VALUES ()` syntax error, but now I see that you've updated your answer. In addition, make sure you close the trigger with the `END` command, which is missing from your example.

Comment: Yes.. Got it that was the problem . i forgot to close the trigger with END .. thank u very much Daniel

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the MySQL documentation for triggers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html