# Mysql auto fill field based on value of two other fields?

Tags: mysql, autocomplete, subtraction

I know its possible to autoincrement values, but i was wondering if its possible to fill a field based on the value of two other fields. I have a table with the fields:

```
CREATE TABLE pligg_links (
  ...
  link_votes INT,
  link_reports INT,
  link_votes_total INT,
  ...
);
```

Field link_votes_total should hold the value of field link_votes subtracted from link_reports. So basically, this is the math equation: `link_votes_total = link_votes - link_reports`. Is this possible without having to use php to do it before data is stored?

Comment: @jiexi: code is always appreciated as it's concise and unambiguous, and can be clearer than human languages. I'm guessing at the table structure. Feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by creating a trigger for `BEFORE INSERT` and another one for `BEFORE UPDATE`:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER trig_mytable BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.link_votes_total = NEW.link_votes - NEW.link_reports;
END
//

CREATE TRIGGER trig_mytable BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.link_votes_total = NEW.link_votes - NEW.link_reports;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Further Reading:

- [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual: CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: care to link me to a tutorial? Thank you!

Comment: where would i put this? Im using a phpmyadmin equivalent.

sorry, im a noob :(

Comment: also, what about updates, will this check be performed when rows are updated aswell?

Comment: @jiexi: Check this question regarding Triggers and phpMyAdmin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324924/where-i-write-mysql-trigger/... Update my answer with a trigger for UPDATEs as well.

Comment: This will *almost* work. MySQL does not support this `INSERT OR UPDATE` construct. You have to write 2 separate triggers. See my answer.

Comment: @Roland: Thanks for that. I noticed and modified my answer.

Comment: @Daniel: field `link_votes_total` needs to be prefixed with `NEW.`, otherwise it will be taken to be a system variable. The SET statement needs to be ended with a ';', which means you need to set a different delimiter and use it to end the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER trig_mytable BEFORE INSERT ON pligg_links FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET link_vote_total = NEW.link_votes - NEW.link_reports END; CREATE TRIGGER trig_mytable BEFORE UPDATE ON pligg_links FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET link_vote_total = NEW.link_votes - NEW.link_reports END; failed : Unknown system variable 'link_vote_total'

Im using virtualmin/webmin for my mysql stuff

Comment: @jiexi: Check my updated answer. As outis noted, I had mistakenly omitted the `NEW.` prefix.

Comment: @jiexi: the reason is each new row is notionally stored in a table called `NEW` local to the trigger. `NEW.link_vote_total` is a field in this table; without the prefix, `link_vote_total` names a system variable (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html), which doesn't exist, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

See:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER bir_links
BEFORE INSERT ON links
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET link_votes_total = NEW.link_votes - NEW.link_reports;
END;
//

CREATE TRIGGER bur_links
BEFORE UPDATE ON links
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET link_votes_total = NEW.link_votes - NEW.link_reports;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: DELIMITER // CREATE TRIGGER bir_links BEFORE INSERT ON pligg_links FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET link_vote_total = NEW.link_votes - NEW.link_reports; END; // CREATE TRIGGER bur_links BEFORE UPDATE ON pligg_links FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET link_vote_total = NEW.link_votes - NEW.link_reports; END; // DELIMITER ; failed : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE TRIGGER bir_links BEFORE INSERT ON pligg_links FOR EACH ROW ' at line 1

Im using virtualmin/webmin btw